# Semi-definite Programming, non standard notation

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, sdp

The usual way to define a semi-definite program (SDP), e.g., as given in Boyd and Vandenberghe's convex optimization book, is:
$$
\begin{array}{cl}
\min & c^\top x \\
\mathrm{s.t.} & 0 \succeq x_1 F_1+ \ldots+x_nF_n + G  \\
& Ax = b
\end{array}
$$
where $ 0 \succeq  M$ denotes $0 - M$ is a p.s.d. matrix. In the above problem $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is an optimization variable, while $F_1,\ldots,F_n, G$ are symmetric (known) matrices. Similarly $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n},b \in \mathbb{R}^n$ are (known) linear equality system's matrices.

My question is, without being bothered by the standard notation as above, can we say **any** problem which has all linear constraints and an additional p.s.d.-ness constraint is SDP? For example,
$$
\begin{array}{cl}
\min & c^\top x \\
\mathrm{s.t.} &  \sum_{(j,k) \in S_i} Y_{j,k} = x_i,  \quad i=1,\ldots,n\\
& Y \succeq 0 
\end{array}
$$
Here, $S_i$ is a set of indexes, and for each $i$ we are summing the elements $(j,k) \in S_i$ of matrix $Y$ and equate it to $x_i$.

The reason I am confused is that writing $Y$ in the latter problem in form $x_1 F_1+ \ldots+x_nF_n + G$ seems not straightforward, i.e., another linear system on $Y$ matrix has to be solved, etc..

Comment: The first problem is what I consider dual form. The second problem is what I normally consider primal form. You can input the primal form directly to say Mosek. No need to convert it dual form. I would read about SDP in the [Mosek modelling cookbook](https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/index.html).